# How to include pdf image in tikzpicture enviroment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

with the following script the pdf image does not appear..., why not?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath, amssymb,bm,color}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
% needed for BB
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{amsmath,sectsty,booktabs,fixltx2e,setspace}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={font issue=\footnotesize},
        font issue/.style={execute at begin picture={#1\selectfont}}
        }
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\td}{\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw=none,fill=none] at (3.7,3.7) {${\bm\varepsilon }$};
\node[draw=none,fill=none] at (2.4,0.3) {${\bm\varepsilon ^{\rm{e}}}$};
\node[draw=none,fill=none] at (5.1,0.3) {${\bm\varepsilon ^{\rm{i}}}$};
\node[draw=none,fill=none] at (3.7,3.1) {${\bf{C}}$};
\node[draw=none,fill=none] at (2.7,1.6) {${{\bf{C}}^{\rm{M}}}$};
\node[draw=none,fill=none] at (4.8,1.6) {${{\bf{C}}^{\rm{V}}}$};
\node[draw=none,fill=none] at (7.7,1.9) {${\bm\sigma }$};
\node[draw=none,fill=none] at (-0.2,1.9) {${\bm\sigma }$};

\node[draw=none,fill=none] at (0,0){\includegraphics[bb=0 0 0 0]{sls.pdf}};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, you have tikz installed twice, and color is redundant.  I had to remove the preview package (whatever that does) in order to get a useful PDF.  Your geometry settings make me wonder if the standalone class might be more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the example is run with `pdflatex`, the following warning appears:

```
Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def)                using `viewport' instead on input line 30.
```

Remove the wrong option with the empty bounding box/viewport `bb=0 0 0 0`.

If you want to put the math stuff on top of the image, then move the image node at the beginning before the math stuff nodes.

Comment: Or use the backgrounds tikzlibrary.